# retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers: What devices will be retrieved by this function?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with bluetooth in my iOS right now. One function of `centralManagers` is `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers`. The description in Apples documentation for this function is `A list of peripherals that the central manager is able to match to the provided identifiers.`.

Now my problem: What are `peripherals` the `centralManager` is able to match? I tested two things:

I started my `centralManger` with the following code:

```
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
```

So without any restoration information. If I connected to a BLE device once, I can retrieve my same BLE device on upcoming sessions. So the function is not searching for devices the specific `centralManager` was searching for.

The second thing I tested is to delete my app and reinstall it after. I tried to receive the previously connected BLE device now again. This time the line is not finding any peripherals. So the function is not receiving all devices which are saved under iPhones Settings -> Bluetooth.

So if the function is not retrieving only devices that were connected to the `centralManager` and not device the phone knows, what are they retrieving then?

Another question: Is it somehow possible to get all peripherals the iPhone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreBluetooth hides the MAC address from peripherals, and instead, provides you with unique identifiers that are, IIRC, unique per app (not sure if they are different for different apps by same vendor). So, in essence, those are not peripherals that are known by your device since that might be a privacy issue, but only peripherals known by your app.

Comment: Thank you! So I do not need to use the restorationIdentifier on my centralManager if I only want to connect to a peripheral again I was connected to already with my app? And I can connect to the same peripheral from different centralManagers? That is awesome!

Comment: Restoration id is used when you want to reestablish the connection automatically when your app comes back from the background if I remember correctly, so, it's not mandatory.